# Plasma-browser-integration breaks with `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"`

Tags: kde, d-bus, qt, plasma, bspwm

I use plasma-browser-integration (not using KDE) to get firefox websites (like youtube, netflix..) to respond to mpris commands like play/pause, and to get the playback status (playing/paused) so I can control media using my media keys and so I can display what's currently playing in polybar.

Sadly, with `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` in my `.xinitrc`, the dbus service `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.plasma-browser-integration` that controls the browser doesn't load.

I need that environment variable because some qt apps like VLC look like shit when I don't have it set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in the latest update of plasma-browser-interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using qt5ct to theme my qt apps, I found that I can use Kvantum instead:

1. Install `kvantum` and configure themes with `kvantummanager`.
2. Use `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum` instead of `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"`.

This fixed all problems.

Credit to /u/Zinjanthr0pus on reddit.